# Losing values not only zeroes during read csv in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have huge problem to read numbers by pandas. When I want to read csv where are rows like below:

```
001234
1245600
123140
```

And so one... sometimes zeroes are reading, sometimes not... Moreover, sometimes also other values like 1,2,3 are also not reatten, What can I do? I tried many solutions like below but I still have this problem:

```
1. pd.read_csv("df.csv", converters={"col": lambda x: str(x)})
2. pd.read_csv("df.csv", dtype={"col": str))
```

What can I do to stop losing numbers, not only zeroes??

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column as a string when reading in the data. Otherwise leading zeros are dropped:

Correct:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Desktop\test\test.csv', header=None, dtype={0:'str'})
df
Out[1]: 
         0
0   001234
1  1245600
2   123140
```

If there are multiple columns and you want to import ALL columns as strings, then:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Desktop\test\test.csv', header=None, dtype='str')
df
Out[1]: 
         0        1
0   001234   001234
1  1245600  1245600
2   123140   123140
```

Incorrect:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Desktop\test\test.csv', header=None)
df
Out[2]: 
         0
0     1234
1  1245600
2   123140
```